# selenium webdriver GetElementSelected class

Tags: java, session, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use [GetElementSelected(Session session)](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html) constructor. my question is how can i pass the [session](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/server/Session.html) parameter ?

In above context what is a session? how can i use above class to get desired element?

PFA hyperlinks

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Please provide some of your code and an explicit question.